# Windows 10 TP UEFI requirements?

Tags: boot, installation, bios, windows-10-preview

Some documentation indicates that Windows 7 can be "upgraded to" (replaced by) Win 10TP. Other documentation says the hardware requirements for Win 10TP are the same as for Win 8. My understanding is that Win 8 uses UEFI while Win 7 (my computer), does not. Can Win 10TP be installed on a non-UEFI system (and will it handle that automatically)?

Will the Win 10TP installation automatically handle creating a MBR and other boot prep when installing on an empty external hard drive on a non-UEFI system, or is there any special partitioning or other preparation I need to do manually first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 still supports old legacy BIOS. UEFI is **not required**.

If you have GRUB running, the boot installation may override GRUB. In this case, install a Virtual Machine under Linux.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if the installation will handle all of the boot prep on a blank external drive?

Comment: the setup is the same like in Vista/7/8, so it detects current drives and partitions.

Comment: I've never installed Windows, only Linux.  Does "detecting" mean that it handles creation of the MBR, etc.?

Comment: if you have grub running, this may override GRUB. In this case, install a Virtual Machine under Linux

Comment: Is this still correct? I've read it everywhere that UEFI 2.3.1 is needed with secure boot.

Comment: @tothphu this only applies to **NEW** PCs/Tablets. Here the OEMs must implement Secure Boot and turn it on.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Interesting why wouldn't I get a pop-up to register under win7.

Comment: @tothphu looks like you haven't installed the Update KB3035583.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Got it now. Next big question will be graphics driver support...

Answer (score 0):

Windows install is pretty much "fool" proof. This does not mean it will always work just that most can do it without any issues. If you are planning to "duel boot" Linux and Windows on the same machines there are several issues that need to be handled. First if you want to continue to use your Linux install DO NOT allow the windows install to format the disk or write an MBR  to the disk. You will loose your Linux boot loader.
Best to either put windows on a separate partition and add it to your Linux boot menu or to put it on a totally separate drive and switch back and forth through BIOS boot order.
Windows does not like to play nice with Linux. If it can it will delete the Linux boot loader or as least corrupt it and make you have to work at getting back into Linux.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you expland your answer a little to explain to how accomplish: not allowing Windows to format or write a MBR; adding Windows to the Linux boot menu; and when installing on a separate drive, having Windows creating an single boot there without touching the boot provisions on the main drive?

Comment: You will have to start you windows install with a separate partition which has already been formatted to a version windows is looking for. you will need a partition formatted to ntfs for the windows install. at the start of the install the program will ask if you want to use the partition you selected as it is answer yes. adding a enter in your Linux boot loader is a long explanation

Comment: I'm actually looking to install it on a separate (external) drive, with its own, single boot provision that is selected in BIOS (no changes to any existing installation).  If I start with a drive where the entire thing is one empty NTFS partition, will the Windows installer handle creating a MBR and all of the other boot prep on that drive as if that is the only drive?